# Display base64 encoded string as image in a PDF file using iText

Tags: itext, apache-commons-codec

I have a base64 encoded string. I want to display this as an image in a PDF file. I am using `iText` to achieve this. I am using `apache commons codec` to convert Base64 to `byteArray`.Below is the code -

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("C:\\Path\\Path\\example.pdf"));
    document.open();
    String example = "...base64..String";
    byte[] decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(example.getBytes());
    Image image1 = Image.getInstance(decoded);
    document.add(image1);
    document.close();
```

This code executes without any error but when I open the generated PDF file it opens with an "internal error" and no image is displayed. What is the problem?

The complete Base64 string is -

```
_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj_2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj_wAARCAIVAUADASIAAhEBAxEB_8QAHQAAAwADAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwYHBQQICf_EAFkQAAEDAgQDBAYFBggKCQIHAAEAAhEDBAUSITEGQVEHEyJhFDJxgZGhF5Ox0dIVI0JSVcEIFiQzYnLh8CU0NUVWgpKVsrM3RlNzdYSiw_FEYyY2VIOUo8L_xAAZAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAX_xAApEQEBAAIBBQACAQQCAwAAAAAAAQIREgMTITFRIkFxBDJhoYGRQlLw_9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9OoTQgSE0IEhNCBITQgSE0IEhNCBITQgSE0IEhNCBITQgSE0IEhNCBITQgSE0IEhNCBITQgSE0IEhNCBITQgSE0IGhNCBL5sSvrXDLCve39enb2tBhfUq1DDWtHMoxO_tcLsK99iFxTt7Sgwvq1ahhrWjmVw17sR7asX7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you tried looking around stackoverflow? I have found something that might help you. First you need to `var imagedata = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);` and afther that you might want to get the instance of image. Basically it is correct what you have written, but there are many guys trying to do the same as you. Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843736/parsing-html-to-pdf-with-itext-image-base64) link might help you.

Comment: Can  you please post the link here?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter before I pasted it into text :D It is there now.